# Not getting developer option on iPad air

Tags: ipad

In settings I am not getting developer option.
Tried with Xcode 6.1.1 (no clue).
can any one help to enable developer option on iPad air.

Comment: What iOS version your iPad has? With the later versions you can not see anything different on your iPad.

Answer (score 1):

The developer item in settings (called "ontwikkelaar" in the screenshot) will become available when you have installed an app you created with xcode. Creating a simple empty app with xcode, connecting your ipad and then tun it on the device should be enough to display the developer item in your settings.

[image: developer item in settings]
[image: developer item opened in settings]